# Why is it showing the syntax error if I have installed python3 and Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Im watching this tutorial on YouTube , how to make a POS software using python and kivy . After running this code

```
import kivy.app import app
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import boxlayout

class SinginWindow(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SigninApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return signinWindow()

if __name__=="__main__":
    sa = SigninApp()        
    sa.run()
```

I get the following error

```
import kivy.app import app
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are typing import twice, it should be `from kivy.app import app`